# Pie chart of value_counts() output, map text to numeric value labels with dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a df.value_counts() output that looks like this

```
> dat = pd.Series(data = np.array([48,37,19]), index=np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0]), name='department')

1.0    48
2.0    37
3.0    19
Name: department, dtype: int32
```

If I do a `plt.pie(dat)`, there are no labels, with plt.pie(dat, labels=dat.index), my labels are 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0.

I also have a dictionary:

```
dct= {1:'HR', 2:'RnD', 3:'Manufacturing', 4:'Fun Department'}
```

How do I go ahead and get the Labels from dct instead of the dat indexes? Doing

```
plt.pie(dat, labels=dct.values())
```

returns the error `ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'`.

How can I achieve it, that really only the string labels are set for the first three values (1.0, 2.0 and 3.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the index and plot:

```
dat.index = dat.index.map(dct)

dat.plot.pie()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That works. when plotting with ax.pie(), I don't get the labels, I had to add plt.pie(dat, labels=dat.index). But thanks!